# How to handle form navigation back button in mobile when using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, jquery-mobile

I am new to the mobile development using jQuery-Mobile. I have three different JSP pages and each page is having form element with `data-ajax='false'`. Form tag is as below.

```
<form action="getNamesList" method="post" data-ajax="false">
```

Now when I click on submit button next JSP page comes with new form tag which is having combo-box and in the similar way when this page is submitted the next page comes. All the forms are having `data-ajax='false'`. So now I want to handle BACK button functionality. So how should I handle this as on click of BACK previous page form should get submitted with its values to populate the page with combo-box list.

Answer (score 0):

You can add back button event handler like following :

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
var direction = data.state.direction;
if (direction == 'back') {
// what you want to do
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks!! I have form methodType='POST' on all jsp pages. So when I click back button on say third page then will it bring back all the data on second page which was brought previously with forward flow when navigating from first page to second using form submit.

Comment: Try this.If previous data is not coming then you can save you data in session storage and then you can read from that.